# Integrating Delhivery shipping gateway in magento

Tags: magento, ubuntu-14.04

I need to integrate Delhivery shipping gateway to my magento site. I tried and integrated but it taking charges 0.00 How do i do this correctly?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/snyzw.png)

Comment: contact delhivery team, they will fix it for you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Answer (score -1):

Delhivery module is not for calculating shipping cost for Table Rate, it is generic and thus do not include any default shipping cost,for this you should disable Delhivery module from shipment and enable your own shipping method you want to charge based on that like flat rate, table rate etc.

Delhivery module will contd. working for tracking and other purposes .

In case you require any further assistance on this , please drop an email at DevOps@delhivery.com